# ¿Como obtener historial de cambios de un numero?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Primero que todo, Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda, lo valoro mucho.

Tengo la siguiente situacion. Tengo un producto que se identifica con un numero donde este numero es (1), pero este producto cambia su numero con el tiempo y puede llegar a tener varios cambios y yo necesito saber cuantos cambio ha tenido hacia atras y si tiene mas cambios nuevos hacia delante. Tengo una tabla que tiene el siguiente formato, ojo voy a poner un ejemplo para simplicar:

| Numero viejo | Numero nuevo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |

Hago una consulta sql desde la pagina php para obtener todos los datos donde el numero que se ingrese en el buscador sea igual al numero viejo en la base de datos o al numero nuevo, ejemplo, si busco el numero 2 me daria dos filas la que dice que el 1 cambio al 2 y la que dice que el 2 cambio al 3, porque el 2 en su momento fue el numero nuevo y ahora pasa a ser numero viejo ¿que necesito?:

Que cuando yo busque el numero (6) me muestre el numero viejo, en este caso el (5) y el numero nuevo el (7), pero a su vez que siga buscando si el numero viejo (5) tiene otro cambio hacia atras que en este caso seria el 4 y este cambia al 3 y este al 2 y hasta llegar al numero ma viejo, al 1 o si el numero nuevo (7) continuan cambiando hacia delante que en este caso seria al 8 y este al 9 que seria el ultimo cambio y me lo muestre en este orden.

agradeceria una ayuda, porque no se como hacerlo, solo logro que me muestre como el ejemplo que puse en el primer parrafo.

Muchas gracias

Comparto el codigo de mi pagina

```html
<?php include("includes/db.php");?>
<center>

<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="busqueda" value="" placeholder="NO. DE PARTE" class="form-control"  required><br>

<input type="submit" name="datasend" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success">  

</form><br>
<table class="table " border='3px'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>No. Viejo  </th>
<th>No. Nuevo  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['busqueda'])){
$busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
$sql= "SELECT * FROM piezas WHERE old_part_number = '$busqueda' OR new_part_number = '$busqueda'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $item['old_part_number'];?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $item['new_part_number'];?> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </div>
<?php }
}?>
 </table>

</center>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En sql no se si lo vas a lograr, porque una cosa es ubicar a un registro padre, y otra hacer una consulta recursiva N veces... para estos casos, es mejor o un procedimiento que te devuelva el resultado, o ir calculandolo...

Comment: Y un número antiguo puede volver aparecer en su columna? O son valores únicos? Que pasa si el número antiguo 4 pasa a ser 5, pero luego este 5 pasa a ser 6 y este 6 pasa a ser 4 nuevamente, sería esto posible?

Comment: @gbianchi , investigando un poco me eh topado con ese termino de recursividad, pero la verdad que no lo entiendo bien, por otra parte, la forma en qeu he pensaado para resolver el problema es que poner una condicion que me compare la existencia del numero viejo obtenido de la consulta sql, pero no logro hace que funcione

Comment: @lsanchezo Buenas tardes, primero que todo gracias por tu interes, en realidad cada numero es unico, puede ser que el 4 haya cambiado al 5 y despues al 6 pero ya ese numero 4 no se vuelve a utiliza siempre cambiaria para un numero diferente, nunca uno ya utilzado. saludos